# Query does not order Firebase children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get my Events in a Recycler View orderd by timestamp.
In my Firebase I have some Events and they all have a long timestamp(year+""+month+""+day) and I want that the oldest Event is on top of my list but the method    `Query lastEventQuery = mEventsDatabase.child(list_event_id).orderByChild("Timestamp")` does not order anything.

```
Firebase Structure: FIREBASE --> Events --> exampleOne   ---> Timestamp: 19000101


                                        --> exampleTwo   ---> Timestamp: 20500131
                                        --> exampleThree ---> Timestamp: 20301101
                                        --> exampleFour  ---> Timestamp: 20501210
```

Fragment with the Recycler View which should be ordered.

```
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            mMainView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_requests, container, false);
            mEventsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
            mEventsDatabase.keepSynced(true);


            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            create_event_btn = (Button) mMainView2.findViewById(R.id.create_btn);
            mEventList = (RecyclerView) mMainV

iew2.findViewById(R.id.event_list);
        mEventList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mEventList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        create_event_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Create_EventActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return mMainView2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Events, EventsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Events, EventsViewHolder>(

                Events.class,
                R.layout.event_single_layout,
                EventsViewHolder.class,
                mEventsDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final EventsViewHolder eventsViewHolder, final Events events, int i) {


                final String list_event_id = getRef(i).getKey();
                Query lastEventQuery = mEventsDatabase.child(list_event_id).orderByChild("Timestamp");

                lastEventQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            return;
                        }

                       ...

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };


        mEventList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class EventsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView2;

        public EventsViewHolder(View itemView2) {
            super(itemView2);

            mView2 = itemView2;

        }

        public void setEventName(String name) {

            TextView eventName = (TextView) mView2.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
            eventName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setEventZeit(String time) {

            TextView eventTime = (TextView) mView2.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
            eventTime.setText(time);
        }

        public void setEventLocation(String location) {

            TextView eventTime = (TextView) mView2.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
            eventTime.setText(location);


        }

        public void setEventPreis(String price) {
            TextView eventPrice = (TextView) mView2.findViewById(R.id.event_price);
            eventPrice.setText(price);



        }


    }
```

I cut off some unimportant parts for this problem so maybe some {} are wrong now.

Comment: Do you know if this is iterating through the children of `Events`? To me, it looks like you aren't actually looping through the children, instead you are just looking at one child.

Comment: Have u added indexing on Database rules?

Comment: whats not working exactly? in the listener you said if it does not exist return.. there is no else?

Comment: There are a lot more values like this i want to retrieve from the Event : final String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString(); @PeterHaddad

Comment: where is child `name` in the database?

Comment: There are also some other details of the Event, like price etc. Its on the same position like the Timestamp. Example : FIREBASE --> Events --> exampleOne   ---> Name: Xmas

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
Query lastEventQuery = mEventsDatabase.child(list_event_id).orderByChild("Timestamp");
```

with this two lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastEventQuery = rootRef.child("Events").orderByChild("Timestamp");
```

In your code, your reference was wrong. When using `orderByChild()` method, you need to point the reference on the parent location which is `Events` node not on a single event node.

Comment: But when I do this my DataSnapchot cant get the values of the events. for example: final String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString(); This give me now a NullPointerExeption @AlexMamo

Comment: This means that you point to an incorrect `DatabaseReference`. Please add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: I understand now. It's not working because you have other siblings within the same child. Near `xmas` you have also `a` and `dino`. To solve this there are 2 ways. One would be to remove `a` and `dino` and transform the data beneath as simple childs not object. Second option would be to create another node which contains only the events as you mentiones in your question and your problem will be solved. Please keep me, should work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  DatabaseReference mEventsDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events")

            mEventsDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String name=data.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                        String price=data.child("price").getValue().toString();
                       }
                    }
```

Put the reference to the parent node example `Events` and then using addvalueventlistener you can retrieve the data. Since your data is under a child(that is under `Events`) use a for loop to iterate inside those children and get all the values

Comment: Unfortunately the app crashes now everytime I upload a new Event and the RecyclerView actualize it. And the sorting does not work. When I have 3 Events now only one Event is shown but 3 times the same. All with the same values.

Comment: To sort it add orderbyChild("Timestamp") after `child("Events") `